# Fill from x-axis up in dygraph line plot

Tags: fill, dygraphs

I would like to fill a line plot in dygraph from the x-axis up and not from the 0 y-axis. If all values are positive, then the fill is always from the x-axis and up. However, if there are some negative values, then the fill is from the 0 y-axis. Is there an option to always fill from the x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to write a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html).

But you should think twice before doing this. If the base of the fill changes with your zoom window, then it has no semantic meaning.

Comment: I'm plotting distance vs elevation, but I'm normalizing the first point at 0 elevation. So, the fill is supposed to represent terrain, that's why I need it to be always from the bottom of the plot to the line.

Comment: How about making the y-axis "elevation gained", then?

Comment: That's what I did, but sometimes you loose elevation form the start, so it goes negative. I'll create a custom plotter and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the custom plotter to achieve the result:

```
function filledLinePlotter(e) {
    var ctx = e.drawingContext;
    // Find minimum y
    var min_y = e.points[0].yval;
    for (var i = 1; i < e.points.length; i++) {
      if (isNaN(e.points[i].yval) == false) {
        min_y = Math.min(min_y,e.points[i].yval);
      }
    }
    var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(min_y*2); // Ensures filling to x axis
    // Fill    
    var rgb = new RGBColorParser(e.color);
    var err_color = 'rgba(' + rgb.r + ',' + rgb.g + ',' + rgb.b + ',0.15)';
    ctx.fillStyle = err_color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.points[0].canvasx, e.points[0].canvasy);
    for (var i = 1; i < e.points.length; i++) {
      var p = e.points[i];
      ctx.lineTo(p.canvasx, p.canvasy);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(p.canvasx, y_bottom);
    ctx.lineTo(e.points[0].canvasx, y_bottom);
    ctx.lineTo(e.points[0].canvasx, e.points[0].canvasy);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    // Line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.points[0].canvasx, e.points[0].canvasy);
    for (var i = 1; i < e.points.length; i++) {
      var p = e.points[i];
      ctx.lineTo(p.canvasx, p.canvasy);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

register to the underlayCallback callback give you access to the canvas and then use canvas operation to draw what you need

```
underlayCallback: function(context, area, dygraph) {

canvas = context;
dygr = dygraph              
// use this value to get the with and height

canvasWidth =  context.canvas.width
canvasHeight = context.canvas.height

canvas .beginPath();
canvas .fillStyle= `rgba(255,0,0,0.2)`;
for (let i=0 ; i< data.length ; ++i){
    let p = data[i];
    p = [dygraph.toDomXCoord(p[0]), dygraph.toDomYCoord(p[1])];
    if(i === 0){
        canvas.moveTo(p[0],p[1]);
        continue;
    }
    canvas .lineTo(p[0],p[1]);
}
canvas.fill();
}
```