# Is it possible to fill only portions of a graph in dygraph library?

Tags: dygraphs

I want to fill only portion of a graph(specified by a x-range) rather then the full fill as done by fillGraph option. Is it possible currently?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to split your data series into two, one for the filled region and one for the other regions. You can then set `fillGraph` for just the filled series:

```js
new Dygraph(div,
[
    [1,    3, null],
    [2,    6, null],
    [3,    8, null],
    [4,    9, 9   ],
    [5, null, 9   ],
    [6,    8, 8   ],
    [7,    6, null],
    [8,    3, null]
], {
    // note: second 'Y' series has a space, to distinguish it. (hack!)
    labels: ['X', 'Y', 'Y '],
    series: {
        'Y': {
            color: 'blue'
        },
        'Y ': {
            fillGraph: true,
            color: 'blue'
        }
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7001/).

This looks correct, but does have the downside of making your data more complex & showing two y-values in the legend when you mouse over a transition point.

The alternative is to write a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html) which only fills a particular region. You might look at [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376976/fill-from-x-axis-up-in-dygraph-line-plot) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I will need to write a custom plotter as you suggested.

Comment: The use case basically is to say fill the portion of graph in a velocity-time plot, and show that the area under the curve(filled using the custom plotter) is basically the distance. Also I will be doing a plotter to show tangents at a given point to show various physical/maths concepts. I will update, once I write these custom plotters, and would like to integrate these in dygraph. Once agian thanks, and keep up the great work on dygraph!!